# React component re-renders when updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a page with multiple steps, based on the current step (tracked by **useState**) it renders a different component.

I have a parent component (**App.js**) which tracks all data changes, and each step is in its own component. In the Step component, I notice that whenever I select an option, a re-render occurs and the selection is lost. (Observed by the console.log at the top of the component in **Step1.js**)

How do I ensure that a re-render does not occur so that it properly tracks the selection?

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Space } from "antd";

import Step1 from "./Step1";

import "antd/dist/antd.css";

const Step2 = () => {
  console.log("Rendering Step 2");
  return (
    <div>
      <b>Step 2</b>
    </div>
  );
};

const Step3 = () => {
  console.log("Rendering Step 3");
  return (
    <div>
      <b>Step 3</b>
    </div>
  );
};

export default () => {
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
  const [items, setItems] = useState({});

  const next = () => {
    setStep(step + 1);
  };

  const prev = () => {
    setStep(step - 1);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Items:", items);
  }, [items]);

  const updateItem = (key, value) => {
    setItems({
      [key]: value
    });
  };

  const stepProps = {
    updateItem: updateItem
  };

  const StepContent = props => {
    switch (step) {
      case 0:
        return <Step1 {...props} />;
      case 1:
        return <Step2 {...props} />;
      case 2:
        return <Step3 {...props} />;
      default:
        return <b>Error</b>;
    }
  };

  const StepBar = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Space>
          {step > 0 && (
            <Button
              size="large"
              onClick={() => prev()}
              style={{ minWidth: "100px" }}
            >
              Previous
            </Button>
          )}
          {step < 2 && (
            <Button
              size="large"
              onClick={() => next()}
              style={{ minWidth: "100px" }}
              block
            >
              Next
            </Button>
          )}
        </Space>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <StepContent {...stepProps} />
      <StepBar />
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Step1.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Radio } from "antd";

const Step1 = ({ updateItem }) => {
  console.log("Rendering Step 1");

  const onChange = event => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    updateItem("option", value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Radio.Group onChange={onChange}>
        <Radio value={"a"}>A</Radio>
        <Radio value={"b"}>B</Radio>
      </Radio.Group>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Step1;
```

Codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-cartwright-sr8ur

Comment: what do you mean by selection is lost, you are updating state on radio change so the new value will be stored in the state.

Comment: pass selected value in step1 as prop. and set that value in `<Radio.Group onChange={onChange} value={selectedValue}>`. it'll retain on rerender too

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the codesandbox example to use the selected option from the state and also updated the ```updateItem``` function to retain existing values, When I select option A and then B, the ```console.log("Rendering Step 1")``` is still showing in the console so I'm assuming the re-rendering is still occurring.

Comment: well how the new step will show on screen if it's not rendering ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you did not pass the actual value in your `Radio.Group` thus you're not getting the actual value of it.

Add `items` in your `stepProps`

```
const stepProps = {
    updateItem,
    items
  };
```

In your `Page1.js` add `items` in your destructured props and add a value prop to `Radio.Group` like this:

```
const Step1 = ({ items, updateItem }) => {
  console.log("Rendering Step 1");

  const onChange = event => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    updateItem("option", value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Radio.Group value={items["option"] || null} onChange={onChange}>
        <Radio value={"a"}>A</Radio>
        <Radio value={"b"}>B</Radio>
      </Radio.Group>
    </div>
  );
};
```

It would be better if you also separate other Steps in a separate file to avoid confusions.

Here is my [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-worker-mkd6x?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the codesandbox example to use the selected option from the state and also updated the updateItem function to retain existing values, When I select option A and then B, the console.log("Rendering Step 1") is still showing in the console so I'm assuming the re-rendering is still occurring.

Comment: That is how React works. Everytime a state changes, the component itself re-renders. In a large scale, it would not cause a major performance problem since React only re-renders the component which needs to be re-rendered.

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, mind marking my answer as the best answer so anyone with related problem will read this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I checked the values by logging them in

```
StepContent= ...
```

The values are being saved regardless of the step i checked by going forward and backward and as the log was showing me the state every time this method fired up i am sure the values are there in the state but on thing i noticed is that you are not showing the values selected in radio group as selected you need to pass the state to props to the radio group as well to show the selected button as checked

Answer (score -2):

A re-render can only be triggered if a component’s state has changed.By default, **shouldComponentUpdate** returns **true**.

```
function shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        return true;
    }
```

That’s what causes the “update everything all the time”.When React comes to render the component it will run **shouldComponentUpdate** and see if it returns true.When you use **shouldComponentUpdate** you’ll need to decide which bits of data actually matter for the re-render.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        return nextProps.id !== this.props.id;
    }
```

Comment: You are answering the question in a class based component approach. Clearly, OP is using a functional component.